# Google: Обновление приложения отклонено(SSL Error Handler)

Tags: android, google-play

Делаю приложение заказчику.

Он предоставил мне проект, я его дорабатывал, от 1й до 5й версии versionCode увеличивал и посылал клиенту, от 1й до 5й апк клиент сам заливал на публикацию в маркет.

Мы живём с клиентом в разных городах.

Сегодня клиент сказал мне самому залить новый апк на бету в маркет, так получилось, что versionCode с 5(рабочий и выложенный) сразу поднялся до 8й(бета) у апк, добавилось 1 разрешение доступ к камере и я включил proGuard на файлы проекта при компиляции(на 5й версии небыло обфускации).

При загрузке я не написал ничего в поле "что нового". У приложения оценка 2,7 в маркете (так как оно с кучей багов, но я его исправляю).

После обработки апк сайт google play выдал такое сообщение:
[image: screenshot]

Начал разбираться, у гугла обновился "Центр правил разработчиков - Злоумышленное поведение"

[(ссылка на центр правил)](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/malicious-behavior/) в мае 2017 года.

Там ничего дельного не нашёл.

[Статья на Хабре](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwir2oqE3IjUAhUKUlAKHYtmDmYQFgg0MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2Fpost%2F231009%2F&usg=AFQjCNEVHZdDLiyKiKUFOGLCnfRTJvTM2g) вообще напугала, что теперь боюсь что-то лишнее сделать, так как клиент платит, а у приложения уже 8 тысяч скачиваний.

**Большая просьба тем, кто сталкивался - помогите советом.**

За год впервые вижу такое поведение гугла

Comment: Недавно в новостях написали, что Google меняет политику для приложений в Google Play. Чтобы убрать всякий мусор и спам.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics получается, у приложения 8к скачиваний и поднимается дальше и 2,7 оценка, добавилось разрешение на камеру и я обречён?) обидно как-то

Comment: Попробуйте продать ваш проект компании Alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне на почту пришло сообщение такого рода:

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We rejected Hoff, with package name ru.hoff.app, for violating our
>   Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update,
>   the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
>
> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for
>   users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that
>   were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as
>   soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
>
> Vulnerability APK Version(s) SSL Error Handler For more information on
>   how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts, please see this
>   Google Help Center article.
>
> 8 To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of
>   your app to the Play Console and check back after five hours to make
>   sure the warning is gone.
>
> While these vulnerabilities may not affect every app that uses this
>   software, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Make
>   sure to update any libraries in your app that have known security
>   issues, even if you're not sure the issues are relevant to your app.
>
> Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution Agreement and
>   Developer Program Policies.
>
> If you feel we have made this determination in error, please reach out
>   to our developer support team.
>
> Best,
>
> The Google Play Team

**Описание которое нашел как устранить эту проблему:**
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387?hl=ru

**Вопрос на форуме с этой ошибкой:**
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SslErrorHandler

**Документация на методы:**
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedSslError(android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.SslErrorHandler, android.net.http.SslError)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedSslError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.SslErrorHandler,%20android.net.http.SslError))

**Пример решения проблемы:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-avoid-security-alert-from-google-play-upon-implementation-of-onreceiveds

**В общем, мне помогла замена этого кода:**

```
@Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }
```

**на этот код:**

```
 @Override
 public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage(R.string.notification_error_ssl_cert_invalid);
builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        handler.proceed();
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        handler.cancel();
    }
});
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
}
```

Этот метод надо заменить в новом созданном WebViewClient, который мы должны присвоить нашему webView.

Сама ошибка появилась, когда я в своём проекте заменил `http://` на `https://` для адресов в webView